# Export PSD Layers to EXR in Python

Tags: python, psd, openimageio

I'm trying to write a program to read in a .psd file, split the layers into individual images (maintaining the original image's dimensions) and export them as EXR files.

I'm currently trying to use the OpenImageIo library to accomplish this but the documentation isn't particularly clear on how this can be achieved in python.

I've successfully managed to read the full .psd and export it to .exr, but nothing I've been trying seems to indicate that there is more than one layer (subimage) to interact with.

Is there:

1. something obvious that I'm missing, or
2. a better way to accomplish this?

Side note:

I have had some success using psd_tools2 but the images can't be exported as .exr nor are they the correct dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually relatively straightforward, however there is one caveat in that it only seems to be supported for 8-bit psd files at the moment.

```
import OpenImageIO as oiio

sourcefile = '/path/to/sourcefile.psd'
buf = oiio.ImageBuf(sourcefile)

for layer in range(buf.nsubimages):
    buf.reset(sourcefile, subimage=layer)
    buf.write('/tmp/mylayer_{l}.exr'.format(l=layer))
```

Comment: Is their a way to extend this to export 32 bit . By this i mean if OpenImageIO supports 8 bit then creating 32 bit is not very far ?

Comment: I'm the chief architect of OpenImageIO, and I don't think it's correct that it only works for 8 bit PSD files. If somebody has a failure case, please report it to the project.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone stumbles upon this question in the future. I have posted why this is happening and how it could be implemented in the discussions page of the github:

https://github.com/AcademySoftwareFoundation/OpenImageIO/discussions/3910#discussioncomment-8913737

The TL;DR is basically that Photoshop stores 16- and 32-bit files weirdly and this isnt currently accounted for in the code of OpenImageIO (as of version 2.5.9.0)

Edit:

I have now implemented it and it will be released with this merge request https://github.com/AcademySoftwareFoundation/OpenImageIO/pull/4208